# subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/aws_neuron_venv_pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_neuron/tf2hlo/aws_neuron_tf2hlo'

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "section_identification.py", line 39, in <module>
    model_neuron = tfnx.trace(model_fn, input_tensor)
  File "/opt/aws_neuron_venv_pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_neuronx/_trace.py", line 8, in trace
    return tfn_trace(func, example_inputs, subgraph_builder_function)
  File "/opt/aws_neuron_venv_pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_neuron/python/_trace.py", line 225, in trace
    graph_def = gdu.run_compiler_on_subgraphs(graph_def, dumper)
  File "/opt/aws_neuron_venv_pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_neuron/python/graph_def_util.py", line 351, in run_compiler_on_subgraphs
    executable, inputs, outputs = compile_savetemps(subgraph_def, inputs, outputs, node.name, dumper)
  File "/opt/aws_neuron_venv_pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_neuron/python/neuron_cc_hlo.py", line 138, in compile_savetemps
    hlo_module = graph_def_to_hlo(graph_def, tf2xla_config, workdir)
  File "/opt/aws_neuron_venv_pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_neuron/python/neuron_cc_hlo.py", line 146, in graph_def_to_hlo
    return graph_def_to_hlo_legacy(graph_def, tf2xla_config, workdir)
  File "/opt/aws_neuron_venv_pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_neuron/python/neuron_cc_hlo.py", line 171, in graph_def_to_hlo_legacy
    subprocess.check_call(command, cwd=workdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/aws_neuron_venv_pytorch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_neuron/tf2hlo/aws_neuron_tf2hlo', '--graph=/tmp/tmpxwpakfew/graph_def.pb', '--config=/tmp/tmpxwpakfew/tf2xla_config.pb', '--out_session_module=/tmp/tmpxwpakfew/hlo_snapshot.pb']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I was trying to compile finetuned tensorflow model in AWS Neuron for Inferentia 2.

Comment: Though compilation status passed...

INVALID ARGUMENTS: Input 1 to node `StatefulPartitionedCall/MultiLevelMatMulCropAndResize/MultiLevelRoIAlign/Reshape_12` with op Reshape must be a compile-time constant.'